# В поле ввода Entry необходимо ограничить ввод символов, кроме всех цифр и точек

Tags: python, tkinter, entry

Друзья, знаю что такой вопрос уже был с определенным ответом, но в том ответе можно вводить только одну точку, а я нуждаюсь в вводе большего количества, как минимум 3 точек.
И вопрос может и глупый, но я не могу понять, что нужно изменить в коде, что бы можно было вводить также только цыфры, но с большим количеством точек.
Буду очень признателен за ответ(:

вот код :

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Okno")

def validate(new_value):
    try:
        if new_value == "" or new_value == "-" or new_value == "+":
            return True
        _str = str(float(new_value))
        return True
    except:
        return False


que = tk.Label(window, text="Введите цифры")

vcmd = (window.register(validate), '%P')
ans = tk.Entry(window, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)

que.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
ans.grid(row=0, column=1)
ans.focus()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю вопрос "вводить также только цифры, но с большим количеством точек"
Что именно ты имеешь ввиду?

Comment: В предоставленом коде выше пользователь может напечатать максимум одну точку, а мне нужно что бы можно было напечать больше одной

Comment: Уберите строку `_str = str(float(new_value))`, через нее проверяется соответствие строки формату float (если при конвертации вылетает исключение, то срабатывает ветка except). Ну и try-except после этого можно будет убрать.

Comment: @insolor После этого вводятся буквы.

Comment: @СергейКох, а ну тогда условие в if еще нужно дополнить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если допустимы только цифры и точки, то меняете функцию валидации таким образом:

```
import string


def validate(new_value):
    return all(c in string.digits or c == '.' for c in new_value)
```

Эта функция проверяет, что все символы в строке соответствуют условию
`c in string.digits or c == '.'` (т.е. символ или цифра (`digit`), или точка).

Пустая строка тоже пройдет через это условие. Если пустые строки недопустимы, то нужно добавить дополнительную проверку:

```
def validate(new_value):
    return new_value and all(c in string.digits or c == '.' for c in new_value)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Comment: Сделал, благодарю)